# Noetherian Catenary ring and Cohen-Macaulay ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring. $A$ is called *catenary* if for any two prime ideals $p$ and $q$ in $A$, $p\subset q$, every saturated chain of prime ideals starting at $p$ and ending at $q$ have same length.

It is true that for any two prime ideals $p$ and $q$, $p\subset q$, if we have $\operatorname{ht}p+\operatorname{ht}(q/p)=\operatorname{ht}q$, then $A$ is catenary. My question is if the converse is true, that is, if $A$ is catenary then is the above condition satisfied?

Also every Cohen-Macaulay ring is catenary (in fact, universally catenary). What will be an example of a catenary ring which is not Cohen-Macaulay?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A factor ring of a CM ring which is not CM would be an example. For instance, $R=k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz)$ for some field $k$. In the same example, let $q = (x,y,z)R$. Then height of $q$ is $2$. Take $p = (x,y)$. Then height of $p$ is zero, but height of $q/p$ is $1$.

Comment: +1 Hi!  The OP's question is an opportunity for me to close [a gap](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=131&L=117) for that question in the DaRT database. I have two questions: 1) would you consider registering a user account so that I could add this example and attribute it to you? Not a big deal if not.  2)  Can you tell, at a glance, if any of the hits listed in the "Consistent with parameters" column is also a satisfactory example? If so, let me know.

Comment: Hi @rschwieb, I don't think you should attribute it to me. I am very certain that this was written somewhere by an expert. I appreciate your project!

Comment: The attribution isn't to you for *inventing it*. The attribution is for you *bringing it to the database*.  I would be happy to add any citations you suggest if you find it appearing in the literature :)  My hope is that this reinforces viewers impression that it is a community effort.